# Virtual Machine: Windows 7 on Ubuntu 11 or Ubuntu 11 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I wanted to begin with Android development. I intend to pursue it as a hobby and it is not my main job as a student. I use softwares like Matlab, COMSOL, MS Office, etc. on my current Windows PC. Therefore I needed isolation between my experimental projects and actual work.

For that I am going to format my pc and re-install the OS. I have two options:
1. To install Ubuntu first and then install Windows 7 on top of it (using VirtualBox).
2. Or similarly install Windows 7 first and then install Ubuntu on its top.

From a safety standpoint, it's my guess, that it's advisable to make my work OS (Win7) the base OS and then install my experimental OS (Ubuntu 11) on top. But please answer my following question purely from the standpoint of performance. Which is better: (Win + Virtual Ubuntu) or (Ubuntu + Virtual Win)? To frame it better I would ask, which is likely to be faster: a given random high performance software operating on Virtual Ubuntu (with Win base) or the same software operating on Virtual Win (with Ubuntu base)? Assume that the randomly picked high performance software has been designed to function on both operating systems (e.g. Matlab).

P.S.: Also if you know a better alternative to VirtualBox, please let me know.

Comment: If you have access I would use either `Hyper-V` on Windows (Server 64-bit) or use `Xen` on Linux

Comment: Windows on Ubuntu. Windows is Microsoft's malware and should be used in nothing besides a virtual machine and a trash bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience Virtualbox performs quite good. For optimal performance and compatibility, you have to install additional packages though (i.e. for accessing USB drives etc, I guess you will need that anyway for android development). So, just use the system you want to use in your everyday work as the base and run the other one in virtualbox. For me, that's Ubuntu. For you it seems like Windows would be the natural choice.

However I don't really see the need to isolate on the operating system level at all. It's quite common to have different softwares for different tasks running on the same computer, on the same system. Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: A clean slate is what I want after a point I don't need a massive software. e.g. I used for a semester VS2008. After trying to uninstall it, it still leaves the traces. May be I am just being irrational, but say Windows when used for a period of 2-3 years will show significant slowdown. So I reformat Windows and the system is back to the original speed. To try and avoid reformatting the system every time I uninstall a major software, I am trying to make Virtual Machines. I am not sure if it's a good idea but I will still give it a shot.